# Solr number of results returned

Tags: solr

when I query in solr, it says for example 1000 number found but it only shows 10 results of it, how can I see the rest?
thank so much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default you are getting 10 first results. You can ask for all at once or page through them.
Parameters you are looking for are:

- **start** (0 is default)
- **rows** (10 is default)

Please read [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)